# eclipse workspace does not show imported projects

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to springboot so I am trying to learn it by doing some examples from internet by importing the maven projects into eclipse. The problem is that I can't see the folders on eclipse-workspace. I only see the folders if I create projects from zero.

1: Create projects from zero:

Here you can see that I only see the folder that I created from zero, while others are invisible:
[image]
[image]

Of course I just can create projects from zero and paste the code from the projects that I want to import but I think maybe there is an easier way to do it.

Any solutions?

Comment: It looks like you created a project in your Eclipse installation directory. You should not do that. For this there is the so-called workspace. You can open projects via _File > Open Projects from File System..._

Answer (score 0):

Change your workspace once and try again.

Also make sure that you're importing the project by clicking on <kbd>**File**</kbd> -> <kbd>**Import**</kbd> -> <kbd>**General**</kbd> -> <kbd>**Import existing project into workspace**</kbd>